# angular local storage on component or service?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-components, angular8

I am using Angular8 and trying to make a login form.

I have an auth.service where i am using a post request to send the login info

*auth.service.ts*

```
login(form: FormData) {
    return this.httpClient.post<UserLogin>(`${this.AUTH_SERVER}/api/function.php`, form);
}
```

And I have a login.component which will get the formdata and send it to the service

*login.component.ts*

```
login() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('action', this.loginForm.value.action);
    formData.append('email', this.loginForm.value.email);
    formData.append('password', this.loginForm.value.password);

    this.authService.login(formData).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.authService.isLoggedIn = true;
        localStorage.setItem('ACCESS_TOKEN', "isLoggedIn");
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/admin');
      },
      (err) => console.log('err', err)
    )
  }
```

My question is, is it viable having the localstorage in the component, in the subscribe, where it gets a success, or should it be in the service?

If it's more secure in the service, how can I have it only set the token on success of login?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Yes It's Better To Handel Token in a Service**

In your `auth.service.ts` add a method

```
setToken(token) {
    this.authService.isLoggedIn = true;
    localStorage.setItem('ACCESS_TOKEN', token);
}
```

and in your `login.component.ts`

```
login() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('action', this.loginForm.value.action);
    formData.append('email', this.loginForm.value.email);
    formData.append('password', this.loginForm.value.password);

    this.authService.login(formData).subscribe(
        (res) => {
            this.authService.setToken(yourtoken);
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/admin');
        },
        (err) => console.log('err', err)
    )
}
```

I hope This Will Help

Comment: `this.authService.isLoggedIn = true;` should be `this.isLoggedIn = true;` as it is being used on the authService. 
Good example though. I have created a different service to handle the tokens, and passing through the params from my component. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to use the localstorage only in services as it makes sure I only change values through my services. This tends to makes your code more maintanable as you only interact with your token through this service instead of your localstorage.

It is secure enough to store the token in localStorage. I personally prefer to then read the token with the same `userService` to then keep in memory when the application is active. You can't only use a service as this would lose the token on a page reload.

If you want an example on how to implement this I have made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/LordChunk/c039d5238be1bd0c6873ac1f514f7930) of what I have used in the past.

Comment: Thanks for uploading that, that was very useful to read through. 
Is it possible to see a snippet of apiService and jwtService too so I better understand the functionality?
I assume your apiService would be similar to my authService, but I don't understand what the jwtService is used for? 
I am looking at making my login more secure as I understand having it set in localStorage isn't safe.

Thank you for this, it's a big help

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a method in your service to set the token and call it on success of login. Not sure about security but creating a storageService for doing these types of works makes a good abstraction and it'll make your life easier while debugging in future.